# Automation of selection in Processing

Tags: image, automation, export, processing

I am currently using a processing sketch to work through a large number of images I have in a folder. I have set an onClick command to advance to the next image in the string. It is quite time consuming and I would like to automate the action that once the sketch is completed the sketch would repeat it's self selecting the next image from the string. The onClick command also save the image the export folder but each time saves with the same file name, I've tried to set up sequential numbering but it hasn't worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

```java
String[] imgNames = {"1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"};
PImage img;
int imgIndex = 0;


void nextImage() {
  background(255);
  frameRate(10000);
  loop();
  frameCount = 0;

  img = loadImage(imgNames[imgIndex]);
  img.loadPixels();

  imgIndex += 1;
  if (imgIndex >= imgNames.length) {
    imgIndex = 0;
  }
}


void paintStroke(float strokeLength, color strokeColor, int strokeThickness) {
  float stepLength = strokeLength/4.0;

  // Determines if the stroke is curved. A straight line is 0.
  float tangent1 = 0;
  float tangent2 = 0;

  float odds = random(1.0);

  if (odds < 0.7) {
    tangent1 = random(-strokeLength, strokeLength);
    tangent2 = random(-strokeLength, strokeLength);
  } 

  // Draw a big stroke
  noFill();
  stroke(strokeColor);
  strokeWeight(strokeThickness);
  curve(tangent1, -stepLength*2, 0, -stepLength, 0, stepLength, tangent2, stepLength*2);

  int z = 1;

  // Draw stroke's details
  for (int num = strokeThickness; num > 0; num --) {
    float offset = random(-50, 25);
    color newColor = color(red(strokeColor)+offset, green(strokeColor)+offset, blue(strokeColor)+offset, random(100, 255));

    stroke(newColor);
    strokeWeight((int)random(0, 3));
    curve(tangent1, -stepLength*2, z-strokeThickness/2, -stepLength*random(0.9, 1.1), z-strokeThickness/2, stepLength*random(0.9, 1.1), tangent2, stepLength*2);

    z += 1;
  }
}


void setup() {
  size(1600, 700);

  nextImage();
}


void draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2);

  int index = 0;

  for (int y = 0; y < img.height; y+=1) {
    for (int x = 0; x < img.width; x+=1) {
      int odds = (int)random(20000);

      if (odds < 1) {
        color pixelColor = img.pixels[index];
        pixelColor = color(red(pixelColor), green(pixelColor), blue(pixelColor), 100);

        pushMatrix();
        translate(x-img.width/2, y-img.height/2);
        rotate(radians(random(-90, 90)));

        // Paint by layers from rough strokes to finer details
        if (frameCount < 20) {
          // Big rough strokes
          paintStroke(random(150, 250), pixelColor, (int)random(20, 40));
        } else if (frameCount < 1000) {
          // Thick strokes
          paintStroke(random(75, 125), pixelColor, (int)random(8, 12));
        } else if (frameCount < 1500) {
          // Small strokes
          paintStroke(random(20, 30), pixelColor, (int)random(1, 4));
        } else if (frameCount < 10000) {
          // Big dots
          paintStroke(random(5, 10), pixelColor, (int)random(5, 8));
        } else if (frameCount < 10000) {
          // Small dots
          paintStroke(random(1, 2), pixelColor, (int)random(1, 3));
        }

        popMatrix();
      }

      index += 1;
    }
  }

  if (frameCount > 10000) {
    noLoop();
  }

 // if(key == 's'){
 //   println("Saving...");
 //   saveFrame("screen-####.jpg");
 //   println("Done saving.");
//  }
}



void mousePressed() {
  save("001.tif");
  nextImage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just call the `nextImage()` function from inside this `if` statement?

```java
if (frameCount > 10000) {
 noLoop();
}
```

Would be:

```java
if (frameCount > 10000) {
 nextImage();
}
```

As for using different filenames, just use an `int` that you increment whenever you save the file, and use that value in the `save()` function. Or you could use the `frameCount` variable:

```java
save("img" + frameCount + ".tif");
```

If you have follow-up questions, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your whole project. Try to isolate one problem at a time in a small example program that only does that one thing. Good luck.